# I want to update the UI of a specific control at once

Tags: c#, winforms

> After changing the exStyle property of the CreateParams class to a
> value of0x02000000 the UI update of a specific control is being told
> sequentially.
>
> As in the example, when a series is added to the chart, the screen is
> updated in the order of A->B->C, rather than updating the screen all
> at once.
>
> Can you solve this problem?
>
> ex Chart.Series.Add(A) Chart.Series.Add(B) Chart.Series.Add(C)

Comment: *"After changing the exStyle property"*. Why did you do this in the first place? Was this behaviour not occurring before that?

Comment: That looks awfully like a homework problem. We’re not here to do homework.

Comment: Use AddRange instead of Add.

Comment: The exStyle property is used to prevent screen flickering.